# Show all database in sqlsrv by php

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I want to display all databases in microsoft sql srv for admin panel, but i have problem with get value. I'm try with query:

```
EXEC sp_databases
```

This query is executed successfully in sql srv, but when i'm try make this same by PHP, im not see value, no any errors or warnings, return null

My PHP Code:

```
    <?php
$serverName = $_POST['hostname'];
$uid = $_POST['username'];
$pwd = $_POST['password'];
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                              
                         "PWD"=>$pwd); 
$connsrv = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);   

if($connsrv == TRUE ){

    echo "connected";

    $tsql = "EXEC sp_databases";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $connsrv, $tsql);      
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
        echo $row['DATABASE_NAME'];
    }

}else{
    echo "no connect";
}

?>
```

I don't know why I not see any result - any suggestions ? :(

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation for this unexpected behaviour is that `CREATE DATABASE` or `ALTER ANY DATABASE` or `VIEW ANY DEFINITION` [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-databases-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#permissions) are requied to run the `sp_databases` stored procedure (I can reproduce this with a server login, which has only `public` role). Set the needed permissions for the connection user, or as another option, try to use the `sys.databases` system view.

```
<?php
// Connectuion
$serverName = $_POST['hostname'];
$uid = $_POST['username'];
$pwd = $_POST['password'];
$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $uid, "PWD" => $pwd); 
$connsrv = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);   
if ($connsrv === false){
    echo "Not connected";
    exit;
}

// sp_databases
echo "Connected. EXEC sp_databases: "."<br>";
$tsql = "EXEC sp_databases";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $connsrv, $tsql);      
if ($stmt === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
    echo $row['DATABASE_NAME']."<br>";
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);

// sys.databases
echo "Connected. SELECT * FROM sys.databases: "."<br>";
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM sys.databases";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $connsrv, $tsql);      
if ($stmt === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
    echo $row['name']."<br>";
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);

// End
sqlsrv_close($connsrv);
?>
```